# How to display numbers from 1 to 100 as a dropdownlist in Yii2

Tags: yii2

I am preparing a signup page in Yii2,at there i have to enclose the users age and need to display it as a dropdownlist numbers from 1 to 100.Is there any code or reference?

Comment: For Users Age , it would be much better if you give a text box option to add into.Reconsider your requirement.Its a good practice to show your efforts while posting here..

Comment: @Lara ya we can and i had done it as a text box, but at the same time if i use a dropdown box, it ll make my form as a neat one

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [range](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) native PHP function for generating range of numbers from 1 to 100 and [dropDownList](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activefield.html#dropDownList%28%29-detail) method of `ActiveField`:

```
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

...

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'age')->dropDownList(range(1, 100)) ?>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Comment: In your sample, options item's value start from 0. so for example if someone select 10, the value option is 9 and return 9 instead of 10 !

Answer (score 3):

This sample code create drop down list from 1 to 100 and so have same values. (and don't start from 0)

```
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'age')->dropDownList(array_combine(range(1, 100), range(1, 100))) ?>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```